# How to connect Go with MySQL to save data and render it again?

Tags: mysql, go

I need to know how to connect my template-works with Go with MySQL phpMyAdmin to save data in tables and render it somewhere ?

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Hello @abdullah. Please, try to Google it before posting a question here. There tons of tutorials on what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with mysql you have to connect database. So you need some mysql package of golang:

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

and then connect database using `sql.Open()` like below:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
```

Now you have handler like register user, first you have to open a template for insert user details and then post those details to handler then get those inputed data on form, then insert with mysql instance `db`.

Below code shows, how to render template from go handler:

```
var register = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("register.html")
        t.Execute(w, p)
    } else {
        //get posted data here and insert into mysql.
    }

})
```

For more details please follow the [link](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/04.1.html)